# How to center content of a GroupLayout in Java applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, grouplayout

I would like to center content of a GroupLayout in Java applet. After long research I still cannot figure out how to do it.

Code below shows my applet. All elements are centered to layout but the layout is not center to applet.

```
JPanel cp=new JPanel();

String[] s = new String[2];
s[0] = "Price";
s[1] = "Name";

JComboBox c = new JComboBox(s);

JProgressBar pb=new JProgressBar(17, 23);
pb.setValue(20);
pb.setStringPainted(true);

JLabel l=new JLabel("Name of product");

JButton b=new JButton("Send a message");
b.setEnabled(true);

cp.add(c);
cp.add(pb);
cp.add(l);
cp.add(b);

GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(cp);
cp.setLayout(layout);

layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

layout.setHorizontalGroup(
   layout.createSequentialGroup()
      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
           .addComponent(c,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
           .addComponent(pb,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
           .addComponent(l,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
           .addComponent(b,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
);
layout.setVerticalGroup(
   layout.createSequentialGroup()
      .addComponent(c,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
      .addComponent(pb,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
      .addComponent(l,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
      .addComponent(b,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
);
```

I will appriciate any help.

Comment: depends on which component you are adding your GroupLayout JPanel cp. show the relative code please. the container of your JPanel need a layout manager too.

Comment: Thats all my code. I forgot only last line: add(cp)

Comment: that's not all your code. I suppose you are inside a class extending JFrame, right?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that code is in my init() function for my applet.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  2) Applets are inherently more tricky than frames. 3) The way to get a `GroupLayout` centered in an applet is exactly the same way you might do it in a frame.  4) Given (2) and that you don't understand (3), I suspect you have bitten off more than you can chew with this project.

Comment: @firstNamer: if you post a short compilable program (an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) that demonstrates your problem, you'll likely get better help quicker. Why the need to use only GroupLayout though? Why not use a combination of easier to use layouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important lines are:

```
        Container cont = getContentPane();
        cont.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(cp);
```

### Screenshot

[image: Applet GUI]

### SSCCE

The 'full' 79 line code is:

```
//<applet code='TestApplet' width='250' height='250'></applet>
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestApplet extends JApplet {

    public void init() {
        JPanel cp=new JPanel();

        Container cont = getContentPane();
        cont.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(cp);

        String[] s = new String[2];
        s[0] = "Price";
        s[1] = "Name";

        JComboBox c = new JComboBox(s);

        JProgressBar pb=new JProgressBar(17, 23);
        pb.setValue(20);
        pb.setStringPainted(true);

        JLabel l=new JLabel("Name of product");

        JButton b=new JButton("Send a message");
        b.setEnabled(true);

        cp.add(c);
        cp.add(pb);
        cp.add(l);
        cp.add(b);

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(cp);
        cp.setLayout(layout);

        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
           layout.createSequentialGroup()
              .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(
                  GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                   .addComponent(c,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                   .addComponent(pb,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                   .addComponent(l,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                   .addComponent(b,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
           layout.createSequentialGroup()
              .addComponent(c,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
              .addComponent(pb,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
              .addComponent(l,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
              .addComponent(b,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: ..and yes - it *would* have been sooner if I had not had to add the imports & other cruft.

Comment: Using a grid bag layout does not answer the question of how one can center with a group layout

Comment: @Simon  If you read *all the way down to the 34th line* (yes I know it's an effort for the 'TV generation'), you might notice that the code uses 2 layouts, a `GridBagLayout` **and** a `GroupLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create vertical and horizontal Glue elements from the Box factory and add these to the sides of your layout. When the layout is set out, the glue expands and forces the rest of the layout into the center.